# How to revert a --record-only svn merge before a commit?

Tags: svn, merge

We use SVN 1.6.

How do we perform a svn merge "revert" of a revision number that is --record-only in linux shell before a svn commit ?

We perform 
svn merge --record-only -c 1234 http://testsomething.com

We like to revert that step.

Thank you
Sincerely

Answer (score 0):

Run 'svn status' and the file or directory that has changed mergeinfo should show as modified.  You can revert that.